# ftp ubuntu connection timed out

Tags: command-line, 16.04, connection, ftp

I've opened 21st port, but still can't connect to any ftp server using `ftp` command.

```
   limmy@Limmy-U:~$ ftp ftp.gnu.org
ftp: connect to address 208.118.235.20: Connection timed out
Trying 2001:4830:134:3::b...
ftp: connect: Network is unreachable
```

What the reason of it? Thanks

```
    limmy@Limmy-U:~$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] пароль для limmy: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
limmy@Limmy-U:~$ ftp ftp.gnu.org
ftp: connect to address 208.118.235.20: Connection timed out
Trying 2001:4830:134:3::b...
ftp: connect: Network is unreachable
ftp> exit
```

Comment: Can you `ping6 ftp.gnu.org` successfully?

Comment: No, "Network is unreachable"

Comment: I'm voting to reopen the question because the IPv6 routing error only occurs after the timed-out yet successfully routed IPv4 connection.

Comment: Can you connect to other FTP servers? How did you “open” port 21?

Comment: sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: This command opens a port in the firewall for *incoming* connections on port 21, e. g. for an FTP server located *inside* the network protected by said firewall. Can you connect to other FTP servers?

Comment: Could you please post your whole firewall rule set, i. e. the output of `sudo iptables -L`?

Comment: no, i can't connect to any ftp
output of iptables -L is added to post. Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. There are no `iptables` rules in place at all. What happened to the rule that you claim to have added earlier?

Comment: I really don't understand why all rules dissapear after every reboot.

Add this rule one more time,but I still have the same situation.

Comment: Ehm, iptables rules aren't saved anywhere unless you write them into a rules list that is loaded at boot.